# How to filter http requests by chrome extension

Tags: http, google-chrome, filter, google-chrome-extension, request

I am working on creating an chrome extension to filter http requests. That means when request an URL, chrome extension can filter some object requests and do not send them to web server. I searched for a while, did not find a solution in chrome.* API. Does anyone know ifGoogle chrome support this, or is there any way to accomplish this function?

Answer (score 2):

There is [webRequest API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.webRequest.html). At the moment it is still experimental but will apparently become stable with Chrome 17 (can be tested in Canary builds). There the API is called `chrome.webRequest` rather than `chrome.experimental.webRequest` and requires `webRequest` permission (plus `webRequestBlocking` if you want to block requests). Other than that the current documentation is correct.